C serial communication, Why does read() lose some data bytes at high baud rates (e.g., B921600)?
Question:
I am implementing a C program to communicate between two serial ports on the same machine. The setup involves two serial ports connected via a Null Modem adapter, and I am experiencing an issue where the read() function does not receive the expected amount of data, but only at very high baud rates.

Issue:

Writing Data: I am writing 2048 bytes to /dev/ttyUSB0, and write() returns 2048 bytes written successfully.
Reading Data: However, when I read from /dev/ttyUSB3, I only receive 2043 bytes instead of the 2048 bytes that were sent.


Observations:

This issue occurs only at very high baud rates (such as B921600) and does not happen at lower baud rates.
The issue does not occur every time data is written. Instead, it happens randomly.
Both serial ports (/dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB3) are on the same machine and connected via a Null Modem adapter, so I expect to be able to read all data written.
I have confirmed that the hardware supports the 921600 baud rate, so it should not be a hardware limitation.


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048
 
int open_serial_port(const char *port_name)
{
    int fd = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
 
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening serial port");
        return -1;
    }

    struct termios tty;
 
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error from tcgetattr");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
 
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B921600);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B921600);
    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8; // 8 data bits
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;  // No parity
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;  // 1 stop bit
    tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS; // hardware flow control
 
 
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // No software flow control
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Raw output
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // Raw input
 
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error from tcsetattr");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
 
    return fd;
}

int main()
{
    int serial_fd = open_serial_port("/dev/ttyMXUSB2");
    int serial_fd2 = open_serial_port("/dev/ttyMXUSB3");

    if (serial_fd == -1)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 
    if (tcflush(serial_fd, TCIOFLUSH) == -1) 
    {
        perror("Error flushing serial port");
        close(serial_fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (tcflush(serial_fd2, TCIOFLUSH) == -1) 
    {
        perror("Error flushing serial port");
        close(serial_fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+1] = {0};
    char *serial_buffer = (char*)calloc(1, BUFFER_SIZE+1);
    while (1)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i< BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (char)(65 + (i%20));
        }
        buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

        int write_total = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            int bytes_written = write(serial_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); 
            if (bytes_written <= 0)
            {   
                perror("write error");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrote %zd bytes to the serial port\n", bytes_written);
            }
            write_total += bytes_written;
            if(write_total == BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

 
        int read_total = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            int read_num = read(serial_fd2, serial_buffer + read_total, BUFFER_SIZE - read_total);
            if (read_num == -1)
            {   
                //perror("read error");
                continue;
            }
            else if (read_num == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
           
            read_total += read_num;
            
            printf("read num = %d | read total = %d \n", read_num, read_total);
            
            if (read_total == BUFFER_SIZE)
            {  
                break;
            }
           
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(serial_buffer);
    close(serial_fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Program output: (run one time)
Wrote 2048 bytes to the serial port
read num = 120 | read total = 120 
read num = 508 | read total = 628 
read num = 92 | read total = 720 
read num = 240 | read total = 960 
read num = 120 | read total = 1080 
read num = 120 | read total = 1200 
read num = 120 | read total = 1320 
read num = 204 | read total = 1524 
read num = 524 | read total = 2048 

Wrote 2048 bytes to the serial port
read num = 360 | read total = 360 
read num = 388 | read total = 748 
read num = 508 | read total = 1256 
read num = 92 | read total = 1348 
read num = 508 | read total = 1856 
read num = 98 | read total = 1954 
read num = 78 | read total = 2032 
read num = 16 | read total = 2048 

Wrote 2048 bytes to the serial port
read num = 360 | read total = 360 
read num = 508 | read total = 868 
read num = 148 | read total = 1016 
read num = 508 | read total = 1524 
read num = 387 | read total = 1911
^C

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Why does read() sometimes receive fewer bytes (e.g., 2043 bytes) than write() reports having sent (e.g., 2048 bytes), particularly at high baud rates? What could be causing this random discrepancy, and how can I ensure that all bytes are read correctly?

What happens if you remove O_NDELAY, that is, if you open it in blocking mode?

I don't know anything about serial programming but do you get the same behavior if you swap serial port names?  Have you tried with a different cable?

read(serial_fd2, serial_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); is not correct if you serial_buffer to contain all the data if there are more than 1 read i.e. it should probably be read(serial_fd2, serial_buffer + read_total, BUFFER_SIZE - read_total);  You need similar code on the write-side.  Not sure why you have both read_total and read_offset.  You should revise question with the output you get from your program (inline not external link).

@TedLyngmo I have tried to set blocking-mode, but the result is same as non-blocking mode. (lost some bytes)

If read() returns -1 I suggest you print errno and continue probably not the desired action.  If read() returns 0 it's EOF and you probably want to break instead.  Also, I suggest you reduce BUFFER_SIZE to the smallest value that triggers the error than compare buffer and read_buffer to see where they differ.  Is it consistent?

Also, you probably want to calloc() memory outside the top-level while(1) loop, or use an automatic variable.

@AllanWind
Thx for your suggestion, I already update the content!

@AllanWind
According to my experiment, it works fine when the BUFFER_SIZE is set to 256 or less. However, when I lower the baud rate to B115200, the BUFFER_SIZE can be set to larger than 256 without causing any errors (lost bytes).

Make sure you revise your question with additional data.  Also, if you edit it anyways you either want to change 2043 to match your test run or just say it's less than 2048.  I have never used it by maybe try run ttysnoop on your two serial interfaces (it's not clear to me if tty_write() is called on the receiving side but easy to try)

If I knew anything about serial programming or hardware, I might hook up a oscilloscope and compare that data received (signal integrity).

When you said you tried blocking mode did you mean O_SYNC instead of O_NDELAY?

Have you tried disabling hardware flow control (~CRTSCTS)?

Check the return value of cfsetispeed() to ensure it's 0 and that serial_fd2 != -1 (for good measure).

Does your null-modem cable use handshake lines?

The problem is buffering. You're doing all the writing and then all the reading.  If the buffer isn't big enough, you will lose data.   Run it as two separate programs or two separate threads, one for reading, one for writing.  This will allow the system to read as the data is written.

I'm not sure how your UART and the driver work, but all UARTs I've used have pretty small buffers. The idea is that as data is streaming in, the buffer can handle short periods of interrupt latency. In my experience, that buffer is very small, 128 bytes or less. At that high baud rate, 128 bytes represents a very short amount of real time. If the interrupt latency is too high, you will lose data. One possible treatment: get rid of all unnecessary code in the read loop, especially the printfs. Reads will emptythe UART's buffer opportunistically. Also, what cup said.

Related to what cup said, have the reading done by a separate thread, and pin that thread to a single core. If your machine has more than one NUMA zone (more than one physical CPU socket), make sure that the read thread is on the same NUMA zone as the interrupt is being serviced, but not the same CORE as is servicing the interrupt. Also, as tofro said, see if the null modem cross-connects all signals needed for hardware flow control: TX to RX, RX to TX, RTS to CTS, CTS to RTS, DTR to DSR, DSR to DTR, DCD to DTR. Some cheap null modems only connect RX and TX.

Is the RTS/CTS hardware flow control being handled by the USB serial hardware or by the driver? Either way, there will be some latency between the receiver deasserting its CTS output signal (to signal that the transmitter should stop sending data) and the transmitter noticing its RTS input signal (which is connected to the receiver's CTS output) has been deasserted (so that it will stop sending data). At high baud rates, the latency could be long enough for a receiver buffer overrun condition to occur, losing data. But the latency would be longer if the signals are handled by software.


I am implementing a C program to communicate between two serial ports on the same machine.

Your C program has an incomplete termios configuration, which means that your program could produce unreliable results. The CLOCAL, CREAD, IGNPAR,INPCK, and PARMRK are salient flags that are left to chance settings. Your program also uses non-blocking mode and performs repeated read() in a tight loop; that is inefficient programming that is polling for data from a system buffer. Check your CPU load while this program is executing.


Why does read() sometimes receive fewer bytes (e.g., 2043 bytes) than write() reports having sent (e.g., 2048 bytes), particularly at high baud rates?

What "confirmation" do you have that "the hardware supports the 921600 baud rate"? Your experience with your program may indicate that "it should not be a hardware limitation" is a hasty assumption, and one or both of the USB-to-serial adapters that you are using could be near its performance limit. Using your program and my USB-to-serial adapters, I saw no issues at 921600 and even 1152000 baud. But at 1500000 baud the serial link is definitely unreliable.
Given that your program is transferring a chunk of only 2048 bytes at a time, and the termios buffer should be 4096 bytes, this should not be a buffer issue as suggested in comments. The receive buffer is presumably an adequate size to receive a full 2048-byte transfer even though your program is clearly fetching the data before the last byte can even fill the termios buffer.
If still you want to pursue the buffer hypothesis, then insert a tcdrain(serial_fd); statement between the write and read loops. That will force a pause in execution for the non-blocked write() to actually output its data. Consequently the first read() will fetch much more bytes.
If you insert a long-enough delay, the termios buffer could actually be filled with the full transfer (or whatever is actually received) before the first read() occurs.


What could be causing this random discrepancy, ...

The likeliest cause is dropped bytes due to framing errors on reception. UART to UART communication uses an analog signal with voltage changes to convey digital information. As you increase the baudrate (i.e. the transmission speed), the probability of transmission/reception error increases, especially near the bandwidth limit of the hardware. The accuracy of the oscillators for the baudrate generators of each UART is crucial, not just in an absolute sense, but more importantly relative to each other.
See What causes UART errors?
If you're operating at the baudrate limit of the device (such as the 921.6 Kbps specified for Moxa UPort devices), then dropped bytes could also be due to receiver overrun. Interrupt and DMA latency as well as driver responsiveness can also contribute to receiver overrun. But a userspace program typically cannot affect or prevent UART receiver errors other than reducing the baudrate.
I have no explanation for the the apparent improvement you see by reducing the transfer size. Perhaps you need to run the test(s) much longer to experience a framing error?
Any receive errors (such as framing or overrun) detected by the UART and its driver are presumably ignored by your program. Your program does not explicitly configure the IGNPAR, INPCK, and PARMRK termios attributes, which is one method to obtain frame (and parity) error information.
See this answer for information on reporting such errors.
A test of a modified version of your code with my hardware saw no issues at 921600 and 1152000 baud. But at 1500000 baud the receiving end reported frame errors, and an examination of the buffer indicated corrupted and/or missing data; the serial link at that speed is unreliable.

... how can I ensure that all bytes are read correctly?

For reliable communications over an unreliable medium, you need a robust protocol. Each message should be encapsulated or framed, and capable of being verified, e.g. using a checksum such as a CRC value, after reception.
Invalid messages need to be retransmitted.
Note that a simple transfer scheme using a fixed-size read() over an unreliable medium is a flawed scheme. You're assuming that the writer and reader can always maintain message synchronization without any support. All it takes is a dropped byte to disrupt the message alignment.

ADDENDUM
You can also use the TIOCGICOUNT ioctl to obtain counts of receive errors detected by the UART and its driver, assuming that the driver does update its async_icount or uart_icount structure. The FTDI and Moxa drivers do, but the PL2303 driver does not.
Adding a routine such as below to your original code:
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>


struct serial_icounter_struct scount = { 0 };

void chk_serial_rcvr(int serfd, int init)
{
    struct serial_icounter_struct rcount;

    if (init && ioctl(serfd, TIOCGICOUNT, &scount) < 0)
        perror("TIOCGICOUNT error on init");
    else {
        if (ioctl(serfd, TIOCGICOUNT, &rcount) < 0)
            perror("TIOCGICOUNT error");
        else {
            if (rcount.frame > scount.frame)
                printf("ERROR: framing %d\n", rcount.frame - scount.frame); 
            if (rcount.overrun > scount.overrun)
                printf("ERROR: overrun %d\n", rcount.overrun - scount.overrun); 
            if (rcount.parity > scount.parity)
                printf("ERROR: parity %d\n", rcount.parity - scount.parity); 
            if (rcount.brk > scount.brk)
                printf("ERROR: break %d\n", rcount.brk - scount.brk); 
            if (rcount.buf_overrun > scount.buf_overrun)
                printf("ERROR: buffer overrun %d\n", rcount.buf_overrun - scount.buf_overrun); 
            scount = rcount; 
        }
    }
}

Invoke this procedure prior to the main, outermost loop to initialize the saved structure:
    ...
    chk_serial_rcvr(serial_fd2, 1);
    while (1)
    {
        ...   

Then call this procedure after every read() syscall:
            ...
            int read_num = read(serial_fd2, serial_buffer + read_total, BUFFER_SIZE - read_total);
            chk_serial_rcvr(serial_fd2, 0);
            if (read_num == -1)
                ...

At 1500000 baud, I'd see the program hang after outputting something like:
$ ./a.out
Wrote 2048 bytes to the serial port
read num = 38 | read total = 38 
read num = 75 | read total = 113 
read num = 63 | read total = 176 
read num = 275 | read total = 451 
read num = 118 | read total = 569 
read num = 75 | read total = 644 
read num = 62 | read total = 706 
ERROR: framing 1
read num = 392 | read total = 1098 
read num = 74 | read total = 1172 
ERROR: framing 1
read num = 62 | read total = 1234 
read num = 76 | read total = 1310 
read num = 310 | read total = 1620 
read num = 80 | read total = 1700 
read num = 79 | read total = 1779 
read num = 62 | read total = 1841 
read num = 164 | read total = 2005 


However these error counts don't indicate the extent of the actual datalink errors as a comparison of the sent and received data does. Such a comparison or some type of content validation is missing from your program. Your reliance on just the byte count can/will provide a false indicator of successful transfers.
